# Can I add a custom field in "Queue build for XXX" dialog

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to add a Number of Custom fields in the "Queue build for XXX" dialog.

Especially "filePath" type.

Can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t that feature now, I submit a user voice here: [VSTS build variable choose file from source control](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18888868-vsts-build-variable-choose-file-from-source-contro), you can vote and follow up it.

The workaround is that you can use predefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. On the *Variables* screen of your build definition, check the "Allow at Queue Time" box next to the variable.

Comment: How can I add "filePath" type? Field that I can choose files from SC.

Comment: You can't specify a type for variables.

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky You can use predefined variables, such as Build.SourcesDirectory (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables)

Comment: It's not good enough, I need an option to let the user to choose a file from the source control.